# How to find the optimal value x and y values from a scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

At the moment I have the following scatter plot in Matplotlib Python:

[image]

I also have about 7 other similar scatter plots but with slightly different z (colour) values but test the same x and y values all stored in json files.

I was wondering if there was an algorithm/function I can use to find the optimal average x and y values such that the z value (colour) is maximized on average out of all my scatter plots, since the values aren't very consistent and vary between scatter plots quite a lot.

(or even just the optimal values of a single scatter plot would suffice as I could combine them into a single one)

Answer (score 0):

Just one idea. I think this can be achieved as regression task. Target value could be the norm of z values at each point(x, y).